# Add stationary text next to slick slider (using inline-block or flex messes up slider sizing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, slick.js

Using Slick slider to make a changing/fading line of text. I want stationary text to the left of it and display the dynamic text to the right in the slider. When I try to use inline-block on both elements, the slider does not size down correctly to allow it to join the stationary text on the same line. When I use display: flex; on the .slider-container, it makes the slider be insanely wide and thus makes the .stationary text tiny, and doesn't allow it to resize even with flex-grow. Please advise!

See here (and comment/uncomment to see inline-block and flex behaviors:

```js
( function( $ ) {

  // Add slick slider
  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 200,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000
  });

} )( jQuery );
```

```css
/* INLINE-BLOCK: Does not allow slider to resize smaller */
.stationary, .slider {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* FLEX: Results in extremely wide slider and crunches down the .stationary block */
/* .slider-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.stationary {
  flex-grow: 1;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="stationary">You can: </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">do this</div>
    <div class="item">make that</div>
    <div class="item">win this</div>
    <div class="item">give this</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tested out your code in JSFiddle and ran into the issues you presented, and it rattled by brain to find a truly dynamic solution but couldn't atm. However i did find a solution in which i just set a `width` on the slider and a `max-width` on the container.

You can see the Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a6kLozb7/18/) with the solution using your code.

```js
// Add slick slider
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 200,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000
});
```

```css
.slider-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stationary {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.slider {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="stationary">You can: </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">do this</div>
    <div class="item">make that</div>
    <div class="item">win this</div>
    <div class="item">give this</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally i'd ask, if you needed to use slick to accomplish that at all and would alternatively use a lighter weight approach as seen [in this simple pure JS (jquery) based solution](https://jsfiddle.net/8azgp041/9/).

```js
const answers = ['do this', 'make that', 'win this', 'give that'];
let activeIndex = 0;

$('.answer').text(answers[activeIndex]);

setInterval(() => {
  if (activeIndex === answers.length) {
    activeIndex = 0
  } else {
    activeIndex++
  }

  $('.answer').text(answers[activeIndex]);
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  You can: <span class="answer"></span>
</h1>
```

Lastly, there is already a plugin out there that I've used in the past to achieve what you're trying to do with minimal effort. It's called "Typed", here is their site https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/.

Comment: Thank you! The widths worked for now-- my client is requiring the fading text effect and I was having trouble getting the fading animation to function correctly on the javascript solution, but given more time would love to dive into that more as it seems like a much cleaner solution! I'm familiar with Typed.js but I don't see any functionality in there for fading in and out-- please let me know if I missed something and thank you for your thorough response!

Comment: Yea absolutely, I even showed my co-worker the slick thing and the closest we got was setting the `width` to 100%, but then that gave it an overflow on the page which wasn't ideal of course.